Not Once, Not Twice
FIND THE WORD HIDDEN IN THE IMAGE BELOW. GOOD LUCK!



 This image depicts a darts game target, each dot being a score and translating that to index in alphabet, we get the letters T,H,R,I,C,E. So THRICE is the answer.


rot13(V nffhzr vs lbh yvar vg hc pbeerpgyl lbh npghnyyl trg abg bapr, abg gjvpr, ohg GUEVPR. (naq gurer ner 6 qnegf abg 5))

Amoz post your answer!

SEB nice try though!

@Amoz I assumed the same but can't get it to rot13(yvar hc, gur orfg v pbhyq qb jnf GUEAPY fbzrubj. V qba'g frr ubj gb yvar hc gb trg n 9 naq n 5 vafgrnq). Curious to see how you did it.

@PDT I would tend to agree with Fluorine here, is there an extra step missing?

No there isn’t.

Oh my bad!! Really sorry!

Here is the edited version

make sure to put hide tags for spoilers!

Can one of you please answer this question!
